# How can I deserialize a list of enums using Jackson JSON?

Tags: java, json, enums, jackson

I'm working on a configuration system. I'd like to be able to load config values from a JSON file and have them "automagically" convert to the Java type I need. I'm using Jackson for the JSON parsing. For primitive types like floats and strings, it's no big deal, but I'm running into a snag with enums.

Let's say I have the following enum:

```
public enum SystemMode
{
    @JsonProperty("Mode1")
    MODE1("Mode1"),
    @JsonProperty("Mode2")
    MODE2("Mode2"),
    @JsonProperty("Mode3")
    MODE3("Mode3");

    private final String name;

    private SystemMode(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    @JsonValue
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.name;
    }    
}
```

Now, let's say I want to represent a list of values of this enum for a given config variable using the following JSON representation:

```
{ 
    "Project" : "TEST",
    "System" : {
        "ValidModes" : ["Mode1", "Mode2"]
      }
}
```

And I'd like to be able to do something like the following:

```
ArrayList<SystemMode> validModes = (ArrayList<SystemMode>) configurator.getConfigValue("/System/ValidModes");
```

For reference, my configurator class's getConfigValue method is essentially a thin wrapper over the Jackson JSON parsing:

```
public Object getConfigValue(String JSON_String)
{
    JsonNode node = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode().at(JSON_String);
    return objectMapper.convertValue(node, Object.class);
}
```

(The real method has some exception checking that has been omitted for clarity).

Now, when I call the above, Jackson correctly deduces that I want an ArrayList and fills it. However, instead of getting an ArrayList of SystemMode enums, I get an ArrayList of Strings and immediately throw an exception when I attempt to use the list. I have tried several different ways of representing the data to no avail. It seems no matter what I try, Jackson wants to return a list of strings instead of a list of enums.

So my question is this:

**How can I make Jackson (version 2.9.4) JSON properly deserialize a list of enum values in a way that is compatible with my single "*Object getConfigValue()*" method?**

Comment: Which version of Jackson are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 2.9.4

Comment: It works if you create an object for `System` that holds the `List<SystemMode>`

Answer (score 2):

The following will provide the correct binding for your enum.

```
public List<SystemMode> getConfigValue(String path)
{
    JsonNode node = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode().at(path);
    return objectMapper.convertValue(node, new TypeReference<List<SystemMode>>(){});
}
```

The second option is to convert the list of String yourself, for example:

```
List<SystemMode> result = jsonResult.stream().map(SystemMode::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Third option:

```
public <T>List<T> getConfigValue(String path, Class<T> type)
{
    JsonNode node = JsonNodeFactory.instance.objectNode().at(path);
    CollectionType toType = 
    objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, type);
    return objectMapper.convertValue(node, toType);
}
```

Comment: The first option breaks interfacing and would require an overloaded method for every possible type that could be pulled from the JSON file. The second option wouldn't even need JSON deserialization at all, so it seems a bit pointless.

Comment: I can see the return value is casted to the expected enum list in the example provided. If you know the expected return type you can pass it as a input parameter instead which removes the overloading issue.

Comment: I assume you're referring to something like getConfigValue(JsonString, MyType.class); This doesn't work in this case because ArrayList<SystemMode> resolves to just ArrayList<Object>. This is something I tried when trying to get it to work.

Comment: It would need to look like getConfigValue(String path, final TypeReference<?> type);

To call would look like getConfigValue(path, new TypeReference<List<SystemMode>>() {});

I have added a third example using class type.